# How to iterate on a hashmap of generics?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, hashmap, covariance

I have an object model which have a parent, that I'll call here MyParent.java. This class have two sub-classes named MySub1.java and MySub2.java.

I have two HashMaps, one containing MySub1 instances and the other containing MySub2 instances. I'm trying to do a piece of code that can handle both HashMaps and do exactly the same thing (later on, having MySub1 or MySub2 instances will have some effect, but not here).

Here is the part of code that does compile :

```
HashMap<String, ? extends MyParent> map = null;
if (some condition)
    map = // get a HashMap<String, MySub1>
if (some other condition)
    map = // get a HashMap<String, MySub2>
```

But now, I cannot figure out how to iterate on the `map` variable. I need to do it through an iterator and not though an iteration over the elements of the `keySet()` because I will need to remove some of the elements from the hashmap.

Here is the part of my code that does NOT compile :

```
if(map != null && map.size() > 0){
    Iterator<Entry<String, ? extends MyParent>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String, MyParent> pair = (Map.Entry<String, MyParent>) i.next();
        // get the object from the pair and handle it
    }
}
```

Eclipse does print me this error message on the line where I do create the iterator :

```
 cannot convert from Iterator<Map.Entry<String,capture#5-of ? extends MyParent>> to Iterator<Map.Entry<String,? extends MyParent>>
```

I really dont get the error message. If I change the first line of my code for :

```
HashMap<String, MyParent> map = null
```

Now the code that was not working does work, but the working code does not work anymore with this error message :

```
cannot convert from HashMap<String,MySub1> to HashMap<String,MyParent>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always put a pair of instances of String and MyParent into a `Map<String,MyParent>`. You cannot put that pair into a `Map<String,MySub1>`. Hence, conversion from the latter to the former map is not possible (as your last error message states). See also [wikipedia on covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java).

A version of the same problem applies to the iterator. If your actual map is a `Map<String,MySub1>`, it returns an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,MySub1>>`, which is *not* convertible to an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,? extends MyParent>>` even although a `Map.Entry<String,MySub1>` is a `Map.Entry<String,? extends MyParent>`. For example, the following will compile:

`Map.Entry<String,? extends MyParent> someEntry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();`.

Another wildcard (`?`) helps here:

```
Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<String, ? extends MyParent>> i =  map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Comment: Your code does compile (did not test the runtime). But your modification is not what I expected and I really dont understand it... could you explain a bit why the `? extends Map.Entry` is needed ?

Comment: I think a part of your explanation has been broken by the site when submitting it. The two `Iterator>` in your post are for sure piece of codes that were not properly escaped by backquotes.

Comment: @Wis This is something that I found hard to understand, too. A `? extends Something` on the left hand side of an assignment need not refer to the very same type as a `? extends Something` on the right hand side. If you find the above code ugly, try moving the "code that does NOT compile" into a method `public <T extends MyParent> void removeSome(Map<String,T> map)`, ans use `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,T>>` inside.

Comment: thx for the answer, generics are not so obvious. The general concept is fine, but the details are kind of tricky. by the way, one of my colleague told me about this that _generics is a way to add type safety when you dont needs it_. He told me he always uses `Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator()` without any type declaration and adds a `@SuppressWarning` annotation to eliminate the compiler warning for uncheck type cast. Both seems to work perfectly at runtime.

Comment: @arne.b Wow, thank you so much. It took me many hours of hair pulling before I found your answer with `? extends Map.Entry` - the topic is not easy to describe in a google search!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirements but having multiple object types in the same map may create serious *maintenance issues*. Hope you would have thought about the following scenarios

1. When both the conditions are satisfied at some later point of time
2. When the behavior of Mysub1/Mysub2 changes.
3. When someone else is maintaining the code.

   I would still recommended to use separate instances. To avoid carrying multiple maps everywhere, you may want to wrap them around in an object.

Comment: The two conditions are mutually exclusive and a former test have verified that exactly one of the two conditions is true, not both, not less. My classes are in fact DTO's that does not have any logical. Just a container to map data to database. For your third note, well... anyone that maintain a code of anyone else always find it ugly ;)

Comment: He does not have multiple object types in the same map. He has a map that contains either `MySub1` values only or `MySub2` values only, and wants to deal with both in the same method based on no specific knowlegde of the subclass' properties, only those from `MyParent`. Nothing wrong with that.